# Sitecore Habitat Performance

Tags: performance-optimization, habitat

We are about to push a site to live developed using habitat.

There are chances that more localization and multi-sites would be developed in future.

But some of the default habitat feature will not be relevant for us (even in future).

Is this a right-time to remove those features from solution before pushing to development or will there be any performance issues when un-used feature/foundation deployed to production.

Comment: I think its not appropriate to pick habitat as base solution to develop any enterprise project.I suggest go through Helix guidelines and it states features is related to business context .I m sure none of the feature of Habitat should be use for project. They are just samples. Just to further help with your question, everything in Habitat is module and it is loosely coupled. You can removed them easily as there is no impact on foundation, project or other features in solution at all. This is the basis of modules in helix habitat.Refer cohesion and coupling design principle given in Helix.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Habitat is an example implementation of the [Helix guidelines](http://helix.sitecore.net/introduction/what-is-helix.html#what-is-helix-and-habitat) and shouldn't be used as a starter kit.

With that said, you should review what you will need now and remove what you can. It can always be brought back in at a later time if it's deemed appropriate.